# Missing table access in PostgreSQL query plan

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have two same tables one having 1k rows and the second 1M rows. I use the following script to populate them.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
     id int NOT NULL primary key, 
    groupby int NOT NULL, 
    orderby int NOT NULL, 
    local_search int NOT NULL, 
    global_search int NOT NULL, 
    padding varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
     id int NOT NULL primary key, 
    groupby int NOT NULL, 
    orderby int NOT NULL, 
    local_search int NOT NULL, 
    global_search int NOT NULL, 
    padding varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT
INTO    Table1
WITH t1 AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM generate_series(1, 10000) id
), t2 AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            id % 100 groupby
    FROM t1
), t3 AS
(
    SELECT  b.id, b.groupby, row_number() over (partition by groupby order by id) orderby
    FROM t2 b
)
SELECT  id, 
        groupby, 
        orderby,
        orderby % 50 local_search, 
        id % 1000 global_search,
        RPAD('Value ' || id || ' ' , 100, '*') as padding
FROM t3;


INSERT
INTO    Table2
WITH t1 AS
(
  SELECT id
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) id
), t2 AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            id % 100 groupby
    FROM t1
), t3 AS
(
    SELECT  b.id, b.groupby, row_number() over (partition by groupby order by id) orderby
    FROM t2 b
)
SELECT  id, 
        groupby, 
        orderby,
        orderby % 50 local_search, 
        id % 1000 global_search,
        RPAD('Value ' || id || ' ' , 100, '*') as padding
FROM t3;
```

I created also secondary index on table2

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Table2_groupby_orderby ON Table2 (groupby, orderby);
```

Now, I have the following query

```
select b.id, b.groupby, b.orderby, b.local_search, b.global_search, b.padding
from Table2 b
join Table1 a on b.orderby = a.id
where a.global_search = 1 and b.groupby < 10;
```

which leads to the following query plan using explain(analyze)

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..17787.05 rows=100 width=121) (actual time=0.056..34.722 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on table1 a  (cost=0.00..318.00 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.033..1.313 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (global_search = 1)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 9990"
"  ->  Index Scan using ix_table2_groupby_orderby on table2 b  (cost=0.42..1746.81 rows=10 width=121) (actual time=0.159..3.337 rows=10 loops=10)"
"        Index Cond: ((groupby < 10) AND (orderby = a.id))"
"Planning time: 0.296 ms"
"Execution time: 34.775 ms"
```

and my question is: how it comes that he does not access the `table2` in the query plan? He uses just `ix_table2_groupby_orderby`, but it contains just `groupby`, `orderby` and maybe `id` columns. How he gets the remaining columns of `Table2` and why it is not in the query plan?

** EDIT **

I have tried explain(verbose) As suggested @laurenzalbe. This is the result

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..17787.05 rows=100 width=121) (actual time=0.070..35.678 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  Output: b.id, b.groupby, b.orderby, b.local_search, b.global_search, b.padding"
"  ->  Seq Scan on public.table1 a  (cost=0.00..318.00 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.031..1.642 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: a.id, a.groupby, a.orderby, a.local_search, a.global_search, a.padding"
"        Filter: (a.global_search = 1)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 9990"
"  ->  Index Scan using ix_table2_groupby_orderby on public.table2 b  (cost=0.42..1746.81 rows=10 width=121) (actual time=0.159..3.398 rows=10 loops=10)"
"        Output: b.id, b.groupby, b.orderby, b.local_search, b.global_search, b.padding"
"        Index Cond: ((b.groupby < 10) AND (b.orderby = a.id))"
"Planning time: 16.201 ms"
"Execution time: 35.754 ms"
```

Actually, I do not fully understand why the access to the heap of table2 is not there, but I accept it as an answer.

Comment: It is access both tables.  `table1` with a sequential scan and `table2` through the index.

Comment: @Abelisto quote from the link "The query must reference only columns stored in the index". However, I do not access only columns of the index!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index scan in PostgreSQL accesses not only the index, but also the table. This is not explicitly shown in the execution plan and is necessary to find out if a row is visible to the transaction or not.

Try `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)` to see what columns are returned.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) for details:

> All indexes in PostgreSQL are secondary indexes, meaning that each index is stored separately from the table's main data area (which is called the table's heap in PostgreSQL terminology). This means that in an ordinary index scan, each row retrieval requires fetching data from both the index and the heap.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Some link explaining such behavior of the index scan would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @RadimBača: See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html and here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/postgresql/operations

Comment: I have added a link to the answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you provided the same link as Abelisto, however, it is not the `Index-Only Scan` it is the `Index Scan`!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the link it makes thinks a little bit clearer.

Comment: I have quoted the first sentence from the link I posted; that clearly states how normal index scans work.